# What is the significance of "text" in defining the type of the script?

Tags: javascript

In the below context what is the significance of " text".

```
<script type = "text/javascript">  </script>
```

Comment: Do you mean as in `<script type="text/javascript">`?

Comment: It's one of the [standard (if obsolete) text mimetypes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html).

Comment: Check [this Internet Media Type article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_text)

Comment: yes....   why do we write "text " while defining the type of script.

Comment: It's just the syntax. A mime-type is composed of a type/subtype. The first indicates the content is human-readable text and the second indicates the content represents javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a hangover from when MIME types were less clearly defined. At the time it indicated that the data was text (as opposed to some kind of binary data).

Today it means "Is a text based format designed to be human readable (as well as machine readable)".

This is why the `text/javascript` MIME type has been deprecated in favour of `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

This defines the content type - there are multiple ones, [as defined in the SPEC](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean as in `<script type="text/javascript">`, this would be the [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), or "Content-type".

The content type "`text/javascript`" has the *type* "text" meaning it's just plaintext (as opposed to binary data), and the *subtype* "javascript", meaning it's the flavor of ECMAScript popularized by Netscape.

Answer (score 0):

It's `text` to specify that it is . . .well, text, as opposed to an `image` or `video`. [See the W3 documentation if you really want to dig in.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-content-type)